# How to retrieve python list of SQLAlchemy result set?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following query to retrieve a single column of data:

```
routes_query = select(
    [schema.stop_times.c.route_number],
    schema.stop_times.c.stop_id == stop_id
).distinct(schema.stop_times.c.route_number)
result = conn.execute(routes_query)

return [r['route_number'] for r in result]
```

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to retrieve a native list of the data rows returned.

Comment: Be prepared for someone to prove me wrong, but from what I remember of looking at SQLAlchemy, it deliberately sacrifices ease of use for doing direct analogs of SQL queries like this in favor of making it easier to map data to objects in Python.  Maybe you could model the data in a way that is more conducive to direct object mapping, or use a different tool for this task?

Comment: the entire purpose of SQLAlchemy is ease of use, when writing a database-enabled application.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

the most succinct way to pull out a list of 1-element tuples into a list is:

```
result = [r[0] for r in result]
```

or:

```
result = [r for r, in result]
```

Comment: doesn't select return `None` if empty, requiring the list comprehension to be wrapped in an `if` statement ?

Comment: execute() always returns a resultproxy, if there's no results then iterating it just produces a zero-length iterator.  the goofy "zip" thing I had there fails though, took that out.

Comment: what about select(class).all()

Comment: .all() is when you're using Query, and yeah .all() takes a different approach here and when the result is to be one mapped entity, returns it as a list of scalars.   but if you're dealing with discrete columns, `[r for r, in result]` is pretty much what i do

Comment: This is pretty much what I had, I guess that's as good as it gets.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The `[r for r, in lst]` syntax is new to me. How does it work?

Comment: @licorna `for (r, ) in listOfOneTuples` basically unpacks the tuple value from the tuple on each iteration. And since parentheses are optional with tuples, you can just write `for r, in listOfOneTuples`. For non-one-tuples, you would write `for a, b, c in listOfTuples` to unpack them.

Comment: I might argue that OP's is actually better, since `r["route_number"]` is easier to understand what's happening when someone else (or future self) is scanning the code versus `r[0]`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would use:

```
return zip(*result)[0]
```

It's more succinct that the the list comprehension methods in zzzeek's answer (22 characters rather than 29 or 31 characters), and for larger result sets the timings in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721902/641332) to a similar question show that it's faster too.

Comment: Note that, in Python 3, `zip` returns an iterator which is not subscriptable. Also, if your query doesn't return any results you'll get an `IndexError` when trying to access the first item.

Comment: Fortunately, it's easy to get around this by advancing the `zip` iterator once and providing a default value when there are no results - `next(zip(*result), ())`