# how to deal with sqlalchemy.util._collections.result？

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I just want to execute the sql：

```
select distinct price from items
```

so I write sqlalchemy code like below:

```
result_list = session.query(func.distinct(items.price)).all()
```

In my db, there are only `2` distinct prices, so the result should be `100` and `200` for example.

However, it returns a list of `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result`.
But what I want is a list of int, such as `[100, 200]`

Of course I can do like this:

```
int_list = [ x.price for x in result_list ]
```

But this "workaround " is so ugly.

So is there a function like `to_base_type` so that I can write code like this:

```
int_list = session.query(func.distinct(items.price)).to_base_type()
```

Thanks very much if anyone can help me

Comment: Do you consider using [marshmallow library](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query for list of attribute instead of tuples in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466959/query-for-list-of-attribute-instead-of-tuples-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Alchemy ORM returning a single column, how to avoid common post processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486180/sql-alchemy-orm-returning-a-single-column-how-to-avoid-common-post-processing)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `_asdict()` method of the result class.
An example would be

```
def get_dict_list_from_result(result):
    list_dict = []
    for i in result:
        i_dict = i._asdict()  # sqlalchemy.util._collections.result , has a method called _asdict()
        list_dict.append(i_dict)
    return list_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned result is a `KeyedTuple`, therefor, when you loop over it - you can write it like so:

```
result_list = session.query(items.X, items.Y, func.distinct(items.price)).all()
for (x, y, price) in result_list:
 ... now just use x,y and price as regular variables ....
```

Just note that `_asdict()` is not an ordered dict ... ( incase it's important to someone )

Answer (score -1):

looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13118371/8953378

you can use:

```
result_list = [p for (p,) in session.query(func.distinct(items.price))]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
return [element.to_dict(show=['price']) for element in result_list]
```

P.S.: should also return the primary_key