# Query for list of attribute instead of tuples in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm querying for the ids of a model, and get a list of `(int,)` tuples back instead of a list of ids. Is there a way to query for the attribute directly?

```
result = session.query(MyModel.id).all()
```

I realize it's possible to do

```
results = [r for (r,) in results]
```

Is it possible for the query to return that form directly, instead of having to process it myself?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486180/sql-alchemy-orm-returning-a-single-column-how-to-avoid-common-post-processing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Alchemy ORM returning a single column, how to avoid common post processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486180/sql-alchemy-orm-returning-a-single-column-how-to-avoid-common-post-processing)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

When passing in ORM-instrumented descriptors such as a column, each result is a *named tuple*, even for just one column. You could use the column name in a list comprehension to 'flatten' the list (you can drop the `.all()` call, iteration retrieves the objects too):

```
result = [r.id for r in session.query(MyModel.id)]
```

or use the fact that it's a tuple when looping a `for` loop and unpack it to a single-element tuple of targets:

```
result = session.query(MyModel.id)
for id, in result:
    # do something with the id
```

The latter could also be used in a list comprehension:

```
[id for id, in session.query(MyModel.id)]
```

You don't really have any options to force the row results to be *just* the single `id` value.

Comment: BTW `[id for id, in session.query(MyModel.id)] ` also works -> no all() call. It is preferred to iterate like this according to SQLAlchemy docs. And that's as good as it gets imho :) . Thanks this was very helpful.

Answer (score 16):

It's strange that SQLalchemy is not providing a proper solution. In sqlalchemy if select a member variable such as a column then each result is a named tuple as @Martijn said. I came to a solution for this using zip function of python

## ZIP Method

[Zip official docuementation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

> zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]
> Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
> from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
> in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

Coming to your example

```
result = session.query(MyModel.id).all()
result = zip(*result)[0]
```

Output:

```
[id1, id2, id3...]
```

How it will work it will flatten list of tuples given as argument if you pass the list like

```
[(key11, key21), (key12,key22)]
```

Zip will convert this list of tuples into

```
[(key11, key12), (key21, key22)]
```

In your case you want every Initial value of tupe that is of the MyModel so you can take the 0th tuple from the list.

## Chain Method

```
from itertools import chain
result = session.query(MyModel.id).all()  # result [(id1,), (id2,), (id3,)]
result = list(chain(*result))
```

Output

```
[id1, id2, id3]
```

## For loop

```
result = session.query(MyModel.id).all()  # result [(id1,), (id2,), (id3,)]
result = [id for id, in result]
```

Output

```
[id1, id2, id3]
```

Comment: It is a very common use case and it baffles me why SQLAlchemy has not made this any easier.

Answer (score 9):

With `Result.scalars()` you can create a [ScalarResult](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalars) to receive single objects instead of Rows. With the Core-style querying syntax your example could look like this:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import select
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

>>> session = sessionmaker(...)
>>> result = session.execute(select(MyModel.id))
>>> result.scalars().all()
[1, 2, 3, ...]
```

**Careful:** If you select multiple columns `.scalars().all()` returns the first column only. So `select(MyModel.id, MyModel.something)` has the same ScalarResult as `select(MyModel.id)`. However, to select all columns using `select(MyModel)`, the ScalarResult is helpful again, as it returns a list of `MyModel`-objects.

Comment: You could also do `result = session.scalars(select(MyModel,id))` directly.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this for multiple columns that does not look ugly?

Answer (score 0):

```
q_stringlist = [q[0] for q in session.query((distinct(Table.column))).all()]
```

for Flask SQLAlchemy

```
q_stringlist = [q[0] for q in db.session.query((distinct(Table.column))).all()]
```