# count how many times in an sqlite3 database table column the values occurs

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been performing a query to count how many times in my sqlite3 database table (Users), within the column "country", the value "Australia" occurs.

```
australia = db.session.query(Users.country).filter_by(country="Australia").count()
```

I need to do this in a more dynamic way for any country value that may be within this column.

I have tried the following but unfortunately I only get a count of 0 for all values that are passed in the loop variable (each).

```
country = list(db.session.query(Users.country))

country_dict = list(set(country))

for each in country_dict:

    print(db.session.query(Users.country).filter_by(country=(str(each))).count())
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `country` is a list of result **tuples**, not a list of strings. The end result is that the value of `str(each)` is something along the lines of `('Australia',)`, which should make it obvious why you are getting counts of 0 as results.

For when you want to extract a list of single column values, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466959/query-for-list-of-attribute-instead-of-tuples-in-sqlalchemy). When you want distinct results, use `DISTINCT` in SQL.

But you should not first query distinct countries and then fire a query to count the occurrence of each one. Instead use `GROUP BY`:

```
country_counts = db.session.query(Users.country, db.func.count()).\
    group_by(Users.country).\
    all()

for country, count in country_counts:
    print(country, count)
```

The main thing to note is that SQLAlchemy does not hide the SQL when using the ORM, but works with it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the job perfectly, and what an incredibly fast response.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to also order this query by count? Found out myself, it was actually easy: country_counts = db.session.query(User.country, db.func.count()).group_by(User.country).order_by(db.func.count().desc()).all()

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the sqlite3 module with direct SQL it is a simple query:

```
curs = con.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE country=?", ("Australia",))
nb = curs.fetchone()[0]
```