# Scalars method in Postgresql does return only first of joines tables

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

For sqlalchemy, I am running something like

```
res.scalars().all()
```

However, I just get a list of `Foo` items and not `(Foo, Bar)`.

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74452716/) for further reference.

Comment: @metatoaster Many thanks for your reply. That does indeed help me here. :)