# Unexcepted return format of filter function in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to get my password of user with filter function in sqlalchemy but it's return wrong format.What is reason of this?

This is my database:
Username: asdef  Password:1234

```py
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///',echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'user'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   username = Column(String(50))
   password= Column(String(50))
   name=Column(String(50))
   surname=Column(String(50))


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
for password in session.query(User.password).filter(User.username=='asdef'):
   print (password)   
session.commit()
```

I expect the output of '1234' but the actual output is ('1234',)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Alchemy ORM returning a single column, how to avoid common post processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486180/sql-alchemy-orm-returning-a-single-column-how-to-avoid-common-post-processing)

Comment: The reason I didn’t think the above is necessarily a duplicate is that I’m not convinced that the OP really expects to return multiple rows from the query. If I’m right then `.scalar()` is definitely the most succinct way to return the value and none of the answers in that question mention it. If I’m wrong, then yes, it’s a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a little on whether `User.username` is unique. If you are only expecting the query to return a single row (or no row), then you can use [`Query.scalar()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar).

> Return the first element of the first result or None if no rows
>   present. If multiple rows are returned, raises MultipleResultsFound.

It would look like:

```py
password = session.query(User.password).filter(User.username == 'asdef').scalar()
print(password)  # 1234
```

... i.e. not in a `for` loop.

However, if the query `session.query(User.password).filter(User.username == 'asdef')` can return more than one row (i.e. more than one user with the same username, and this is perhaps what you intend here, as you are accessing the query in a for loop) than `.scalar()` will fail as internally it uses `Query.one()` which raises `MultipleResultsFound` exception if a query returns more than one row. In that case you really just need to index out the password or get it using attribute lookup (the row proxy can do either):

```py
for row in session.query(User.password).filter(User.username == 'asdef'):
    # both of these will print the same thing, but the second one
    # makes for nicer reading!
    print(row[0])
    print(row.password)

# output:
# 1234
# 1234
```