# SQLAlchemy(Python): TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "RowProxy") to tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am executing a select query which would return a single column and I am trying to convert the returned Row object to tuple. But I seem to be getting below error:

```
    ids = sum(tuple(conn.execute('select id from some_database.some_table')), ()) 
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "RowProxy") to tuple
```

Sample Code:

```
with sqlalchemy_engine.connect() as conn:
    ids = sum(tuple(conn.execute('select id from some_database.some_table')), ())   # statement causing error
    print(ids)
```

Expected Output:

```
('123','456','789')
```

I can iterate output of *select* query and append/print the values one by one, but would rather use the one-liner

**Edit:**

The column `id` in query `select id from some_database.some_table` has alphanumeric values. So the expected output could be:
`('ff123', 'df456', 'gv789')`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486180/sql-alchemy-orm-returning-a-single-column-how-to-avoid-common-post-processing) answer your question?  (If I understand your question correctly, you want to flatten the collection of tuples into a collection of `int`s)

Comment: Hi, @snakecharmerb, Output of `tuple(conn.execute('select id from some_database.some_table')` is `(('123',), ('456',))`. I want to convert it to `('123','456')` without changes it from string to int as I  am using these value in later sql query. Example: `select *** from *** where id in ('123','456')`

Comment: So `ids = tuple(r for r, in conn.execute(...))`?

Comment: Yeah, like I mentioned in my question, I can use for loop, but what I want to know is, why this didn't work - `sum(tuple(conn.execute('select id from some_database.some_table')), ())`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have wrong parenthesis placement.

```py
sum(tuple(conn.execute('select id from some_database.some_table')), ())
```

Should be fixed to

```py
sum(tuple(conn.execute('select id from some_database.some_table'), ()))
```

This will make the `tuple` call successful.
Since you were calling `tuple(conn.execute(...), ())` it indeed tried to concatenate the result of `conn.execute` and a `()`.

**NOTE** that converting your `RowProxy` to a tuple, will make a result mentioned in the comments - `(('123',), ('456',))`, so you could better use a `map` to unpack the values and make them flat:

```py
value = sum(
    map(
        lambda x: x[0],
        conn.execute(..., ())
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi @Icebreaker454, your solution `sum(tuple(conn.execute('select id from some_database.some_table'), ()))` caused error: `TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: And the lambda solution u mentioned caused error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`


This is the code I tried: `sum(map(lambda x: x[0], conn.execute('select id from some_database.some_table', ())))`

Comment: I suppose for lambda you should try to make the result an integer (or whatever datatype you have on your db) like this `lambda x: int(x[0])`

Comment: Hi, please check the edit, output column has alphanumeric values, so casting is not an option.

Comment: You can't possibly sum string values, so you have to write some kind of filtering function. E.g. having a value `ab123`, this function can decide how to extract any number info from it. It would be named like `def predicate(value):`, and you can feed it in place of lambda to the map.